# Counters increase indefinitely. How to reset?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I have the below code. However when plotted the counters increase indefinitely. I want to count only once per candle. How would I reset the count each candle?

```
//@version=4
study("bull/bear count")
var Bullcor = 0
var Bearcor = 0

currency1 = input("EURUSD", title="Positive Correlation 1")

security1 = security(currency1,"15",close)

ema50s1 =ema(security1,50)

ema200s1 =ema(security1,200)

if ema50s1>ema200s1
    Bullcor := Bullcor + 1

if ema50s1<ema200s1
    Bearcor := Bearcor + 1

// debug:    
plot(Bullcor, color = color.green)
plot(Bearcor, color = color.red)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `var` keyword or change it to `int`

```
int Bullcor = 0
int Bearcor = 0
```

This way the script will assign `0` to `Bullcor` and `Bearcor` variables on every new candle and after that will check the `if` statements.